# Module 'dialogflow_v2.types' has no 'QueryInput' member

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I tried to call the dialogflow api using python but getting error as

> Module 'dialogflow_v2.types' has no 'QueryInput' member

please help me out.

```py
import dialogflow

def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

    for text in texts:
        text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
        response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)

        print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(response.query_result.fulfillment_text)) 

detect_intent_texts("upcl-b0ba9","abcd",["hello"],"en-US")
```

Comment: Any update for this question? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution of your problem
instead of

```
import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow 

text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
```

try like this

```
from dialogflow_v2.types import TextInput, QueryInput

text_input = TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
query_input = QueryInput(text=text_input)
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs due to a linter package called pylint. You can simply uninstall it by typing:

```
    pip uninstall pylint
```

Comment: pylint is not installed

Comment: I tried recreating your problem, I could find only a couple of reasons that were causing it.   
   
1). Use of lint / linter tool. So, uninstalling it resolved issue. (though this doesn't seem to work in your case.)  
    
2). During the first installation of this package, `pip` fetched the previous stable version which created some compatibility issues, so a simple update solved the issue.  
    `pip install --upgrade dialogflow`   
   
You can check your module version by running  `pip freeze'  

The following version should be there in the list:  `dialogflow==0.6.0`